# Unable to connect OBD2 scan tool

Tags: obd-ii, mitsubishi, lancer, scan-tool

Cheerz,

I have purchased recently OBD2 scan tool(Autel MaxiScan MS300) which supports ISO9141. My car (Mitsubishi Lancer GLX 1.3 1999) seems like ODB2 compatible using ISO9141-2 protocol for communication (checked [here](http://pinoutsguide.com/CarElectronics/mitsubishi_obd2_daig_pinout.shtml)). I plug the tool, it initialized, I turn the key to "OK" position (the one which is indicated in the manual), the tool goes through different protocols and at the end reports that it is unable to communicate with my car. I have searched for solution, some people told that it is possible to be that some of the fuses is burnt, I have checked today all the fuses, cleaned contacts, still without luck. Are there any other issues which might be causing the problem in communication of the tool and the car?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could anyone point me also which tags I should add? I do not have enough reputation to add ODB2..

Comment: It might help if you added the brand/model of the scan tool you are trying to use.

Comment: added the name of the tool to the post Autel MaxiScan MS300

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be working. The ISO 9141-2 is the Chrysler protocol, but I believe the 1999 Mitsu was when Chrysler and they were still in bed together. I read on Amazon that someone described initialization of the tool as: Plug in; self power on; turn ignition to on; press enter to start the tool registration. I would bet that is what you are doing, but thought I'd throw it out there.

Comment: I will have to try on another vehicle, which is also OBD2 compatible (though it only will be possible in few weeks). Going to report the findings..

Comment: Have you resolved your scan tool issue?

Comment: Not really :S. Just gave it to my father, because it seemed to work on his car.